# Angularjs / Bootstrap Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

good morning
I write app in Anuglar and Bootstrap, and i used ui.router to routes(works good), and when i load bootstrap library i have this error: 
console:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!

index.html

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript-lazy"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript-lazy"></script>
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it solves your problem or not, but angular doesn't use bootstrap as it is, it use a customized version of it [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) it is, use it instead of normal bootstrap